# Nunit 3: Can tests in one class run in parallel with Parallelizable attribute?

Tags: c#, nunit-3.0

I am using

```
 [TestFixture]
 [Parallelizable(ParallelScope.Children)]
 public class MyTests
 {
 }
```

There are 5 tests within this class.

I am using NUnit 3 Test Adapter.

I also have the below in my AssemblyInfo of test project:

```
[assembly: Parallelizable(ParallelScope.Fixtures)]
```

In the test window I notice that multiple classes are running in parallel. However, the tests within each class are run synchronously.

How can I achieve parallelism within each class?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried

`[assembly: Parallelizable(ParallelScope.All)]`

which, according to test explorer progress indicators, caused multiple test methods to run in parallel. This option als was slightly faster than

`ParallelScope.Fixtures`

I am using NUnit3TestAdapter version 4.3.1 in VS 2022.